# Let X be a subset of {1,2,...,2014}...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, computer-science

Let X be a subset of {1,2,...,2014}.

How would I show that if |X| ≥ 64, then there exist at least two different pairs {x,y} and {u,v} of distinct elements of X which |x-y|=|u-v|?

I'm not too sure how to go about this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $|X|\ge 64$, there exist $\frac12 \times 64\times 63 =\frac12 \times 4032=2016$  unordered pairs. And any pair satisfies $0 <|x-y|\le 2013$ since $X \subset \{1,2.\cdots,2014\}$ .

As we kmow $2013< 2016$, therfore there must exist two pairs  $\{x,y\}$ and $\{u,v\}$ of distinct elements of $X$ for which $|x-y|=|u-v|$.

Answer (score 1):

How many pairs are there?  Can all the differences be different?

Comment: Do you mean how many pairs are there in $X$ or in the universal set?

Answer (score 0):

Order the elements of $X$, $x_1<x_2<\dots<x_{64}$.

If all the gaps between consecutive elements ($x_{i+1}-x_i$) were different, we'd have that the sum of the gap sizes is at least $1+2+\cdots+63=\frac{63\cdot 64}{2}>2014$.  Hence at least two pairs of the consecutive elements must have the same gap size.